# error mysql query using select subquery with count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i'm trying to select and count record from another table and check the count if greater than 0

table 1 = the table im getting the records

```
STRUCTURE:
id | username | sponsorid
```

table 2 = the table im trying to get the count and check if count is greater than 0

```
STRUCTURE: 
id | receiver_id | amount
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT t1.id AS lev1, t2.id AS lev2, t3.id AS lev3, t4.id AS lev4, t5.id AS lev5, 
  t6.id AS lev6, t7.id AS lev7, t8.id AS lev8, t9.id AS lev9, t10.id AS lev10 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_fund where receiver_id = 1) as entry_count 
FROM tbl_users AS t1 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t2 
    ON t2.sponsorid = t1.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t3 
    ON t3.sponsorid = t2.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t4 
    ON t4.sponsorid = t3.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t5 
    ON t5.sponsorid = t4.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t6 
    ON t6.sponsorid = t5.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t7 
    ON t7.sponsorid = t6.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t8 
    ON t8.sponsorid = t7.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t9 
    ON t9.sponsorid = t8.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t10 
    ON t10.sponsorid = t9.id 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t11 
    ON t11.sponsorid = t10.id 
WHERE t1.sponsorid = 1 
HAVING entry_count > 0
```

ERROR:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_fund where receiver_id = 1) as entry_count FROM' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT t1.id AS lev1, t2.id AS lev2, t3.id AS lev3, t4.id AS lev4, t5.id AS lev5, t6.id AS lev6, t7.id AS lev7, t8.id AS lev8, t9.id AS lev9, t10.id AS lev10 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_fund where receiver_id = 1) as entry_count FROM tbl_atest_unilevel AS t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t2 ON t2.sponsorid = t1.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t3 ON t3.sponsorid = t2.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t4 ON t4.sponsorid = t3.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t5 ON t5.sponsorid = t4.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t6 ON t6.sponsorid = t5.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t7 ON t7.sponsorid = t6.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t8 ON t8.sponsorid = t7.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t9 ON t9.sponsorid = t8.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t10 ON t10.sponsorid = t9.id LEFT JOIN tbl_atest_unilevel AS t11 ON t11.sponsorid = t10.id WHERE t1.sponsorid = 1 HAVING entry_count > 0 )
```

EDIT: Now it show's like this. But i want to check the count on every user for each level

[image]

What i'm trying to accomplish is only get the users if they have record in table2

Comment: Add a comma after `lev10`

Comment: no error's now but i want to count every user in each level

Comment: i edited my question @WebCode.ie

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.  Please explain a bit more about your table structure? How does `table 1` relate to `table 2`?

Comment: table 1 has all the members user id, and table2 has the column of receiver_id, receiver_id = table1 id

Comment: i'm trying to check every id in table2 by counting if the id is listed in table 2. if the query see that there's a record in table 2, it will show get the user and include in either level 1 to 10

Comment: @waterloomatt What i'm trying to accomplish is only get the users if they have record in table2

Comment: `> only get the users if they have a record in table2` - so then use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`. But, something is still wrong here. You shouldn't have to join to the same table so many times. What you need is a `GROUP BY` and `INNER JOIN`. But before you start with the query, have another look at your table design. Can you explain what you're trying to do here? What is a `sponsor`, `receiver`, `master_fund`? I think if you get your table structure right first, the query will become very easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma after lev10

The correct query is

```
SELECT t1.id AS lev1, t2.id AS lev2, t3.id AS lev3, t4.id AS lev4, t5.id AS lev5, t6.id AS lev6, t7.id AS lev7, t8.id AS lev8, t9.id AS lev9, t10.id AS lev10, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_fund where receiver_id = 1) as entry_count FROM tbl_users AS t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t2 ON t2.sponsorid = t1.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t3 ON t3.sponsorid = t2.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t4 ON t4.sponsorid = t3.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t5 ON t5.sponsorid = t4.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t6 ON t6.sponsorid = t5.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t7 ON t7.sponsorid = t6.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t8 ON t8.sponsorid = t7.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t9 ON t9.sponsorid = t8.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t10 ON t10.sponsorid = t9.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t11 ON t11.sponsorid = t10.id WHERE t1.sponsorid = 1 HAVING entry_count > 0
```

Comment: yes no errors now, but i want to get the users if they have record in tbl_master_fund.

Comment: your query looks like this https://s22.postimg.cc/ievcbtxg1/level.png  but i want the user will only show if they have records in table 2

Answer (score 0):

missed a comma after lev10

```
   SELECT t1.id AS lev1, t2.id AS lev2, t3.id AS lev3, t4.id AS lev4, t5.id AS lev5, t6.id AS lev6, t7.id AS lev7, t8.id AS lev8, t9.id AS lev9, t10.id AS lev10, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_master_fund where receiver_id = 1) as entry_count FROM tbl_users AS t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t2 ON t2.sponsorid = t1.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t3 ON t3.sponsorid = t2.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t4 ON t4.sponsorid = t3.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t5 ON t5.sponsorid = t4.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t6 ON t6.sponsorid = t5.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t7 ON t7.sponsorid = t6.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t8 ON t8.sponsorid = t7.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t9 ON t9.sponsorid = t8.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t10 ON t10.sponsorid = t9.id LEFT JOIN tbl_users AS t11 ON t11.sponsorid = t10.id WHERE t1.sponsorid = 1 HAVING entry_count > 0
```

Comment: Should read the already provided answers before adding yours.

Comment: your query looks like this s22.postimg.cc/ievcbtxg1/level.png but i want the user will only show if they have records in table 2